# Missing values in sequence into actual sequence in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of integers, for example, `v <- c(1,5,1,2,2,4,7,5,7)`. If I `sort(unique(v))`, the values 3 and 6 would be missing in the sequence. How can I transform `v` into a vector where `sort(unique(v))` is an actual sequence of integers? This is, transforming `v` into `c(1,4,1,2,2,3,5,3,5)` (in general, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting `v` to factor and back to numeric could do the trick

```
as.numeric(as.factor(v))
#[1] 1 4 1 2 2 3 5 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using OP's method, we get the expected output with `match`

```
match(v, sort(unique(v)))
#[1] 1 4 1 2 2 3 5 4 5
```